# Plot graph from Database (Sqlite) data source wih zooming and navigation option, targeting all availbale web browsers

Tags: tcl

I want to plot a graph using Sqlite database data, and put this graph in a Html page, with different editing options (selection, Zooming. and navigation)

Answer (score 1):

My colleague Donal of course tells the truth when he writes above, "... likely to involve plenty of Javascript ..."

There *are* other possibilities, though.  I wonder what "a graph" means to CP_IS, particularly in light of the requirement for "... navigation."  In any case, on the low end, there are such light-weight solutions as "Simple bar chart" in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-sc4/.

If CP_IS is willing to consider HTML5 (and http://www.itworld.com/development/103308/html5-tipping-point-developers-not-browsers makes the case that he should), **canvas** and SVG are available to him, and they certainly open up superb opportunities for fast graphing, zooming, and so on.

Finally, while CP_IS's tagging of this question as related to Tcl (am I reading that correctly?) puzzles me, if he's already working with Tcl, I suspect Æjaks http://wiki.tcl.tk/17422 will interest him.

Comment: I mean by graph "time series graphs" like the stock index graph. http://finance.google.com/,
Is it better to plot the graph on the client side, or on the server side then load it to the Page?
I'm not considering HTML5, as I'm targeting old versions of variety of web browsers installed on different platforms (Linux, solaris, AIX)

Comment: My apology, CP_IS; life intervened, and I needed to be away for a while.

I repeat:  I don't get the Tcl connection in your situation.  My advice:  go to full-time JavaScript people, and ask *them* for a quick solution to client-side graphing which includes "selection, Zooming. and navigation".  My own knowledge is sufficiently primitive that I'm most comfortable writing the JavaScript for this myself, while those with more current experience can surely advise you about which library best fits your requirements.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Graphing in a browser is likely to involve plenty of Javascript and jQuery; [this](http://xaviershay.github.com/tufte-graph/) looks like a likely helper library.